# How to reshape dataset using python like this

Tags: reshape

This is the raw data

```
a=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],
   [7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

I want to convert it to the format like this:

```
b=[[1,2,3,7,8,9],
   [4,5,6,10,11,12]]

array(List).swapaxes()
```

How to do it use reshape and swapaxes in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12]])
b = a.reshape((2, 2, 3)).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(2, 6)
print(b)
```

check it out: https://coderpad.io/F7X7EKR4

Comment: You combine the [1,2,3] and [7,8,9] by reshape(2, 6). Was that the question?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot